CSV exportGrid file data not clearing between dijit.byId options
I've coded a pair of tabs (User Inbox and Group Inbox) that are to save their respective, tabled page content as a CSV and export the data to Excel. The problem is after initially exporting the User Inbox content (containing a handful of rows) successfully, and then exporting the Group Inbox content (containing the data of both tabs) successfully, a subsequent attempt to export the User Inbox (during the same session) sends the data of both tabs, instead on the handful of rows exported the first time.
It almost seems like a buffer needs to be part of the code to clear any buffer/data after each tab has its proper CSV records exported. And doing a Shift/browser refresh doesn't clear the issue up. Didn't know if there were any thoughts?
on(dom.byId("exportGrids"), "click", function(){
var exportData;
    //6 rows        
    dijit.byId("userInboxGrid").exportGrid("csv", function(gridData) {
        exportData = gridData;
        dom.byId("exportData").value = exportData;
    });
    
    //the 6 rows of the User Inbox tab + those of the Group Inbox tab
    dijit.byId("groupInboxGrid").exportGrid("csv", function(gridData) {
        exportData = exportData + gridData;
        dom.byId("exportData").value = exportData;
    }); 

    return true;
});

Thnks,
Dave
